# How to define macro for colored text?

Tags: macros, color

I know that it is possible to obtain colored text in Latex by including the color package and writing like

```
\textcolor{red}{This is red text}
```

How could I define a macro which would produce text of a given color such as

```
\red{This is red text}
```

?

Comment: `\newcommand\red[1]{\color{red}#1}` isn't good enough? Why you don't want to use `\textcolor`, too verbose? Maybe the question actually was about defining own macros? If yes, then see e.g. [LaTeX/Customizing LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX) from LaTeX wikibook.

Comment: @przemoc: Your macro will switch to red color for *every* text following it, not only the macro's argument. Correct would be (e.g.) `\newcommand\red[1]{{\color{red}#1}}` (note the additional set of braces).

Comment: @lockstep: Damn, right! Forgot about them...

Comment: @Ihahne: The command `\red` is defined in `pstricks` and therefore leads to errors. You can overcome this conflict by `\renewcommand\red[1]{{\color{red}#1}}` or better define a new command like `\newcommand\txtred[1]{{\color{red}#1}}`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}` works.  Or are you trying to do something more general, such that `\somecolorname{foo}` behaves the same as `\textcolor{somecolorname}{foo}`?  That latter case is probably not a good idea...

Comment: A `\newcommand*{\red}{\textcolor{red}}` is actually fine enough. There is no need to pass the argument around. Also `\textcolor` simply calls `\color` internally, so `\newcommand\red[1]{{\color{red}#1}}` would be more efficient.  However I would go with `\newcommand*\red{\color{red}}`, then you can write `{\red text}` instead of `\ref{text}` and also use `\red` to switch to red for the rest of the group.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, it's true that you can elide the argument.  And it's more efficient TeX, too (actually, it's more efficient programming in nearly any language).  On the other hand, it is slightly odd-looking and takes a bit of TeXpertise to understand a command definition that effectively takes one more invisible argument.  So unless I need the subtly different semantics of leaving off the argument (because of brace groups), or really am worried about the efficiency, I tend to leave the argument in for clarity's sake.