# What are the differences between creating a new macro command vs. a new environment?

Tags: macros, color, environments

For the purposes of collaboration, I want to create a number of short commands or environments that will color the text within its scope so as to identify the author.

My first thought was to simply create a number of new commands along the lines of the suggestions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/how-to-define-macro-for-colored-text). But I'm imagining that the various collaborators would be writing several pages of text at a time and I don't know whether large blocks of text (and perhaps multiple new environments within that text) brings with it issues that would decide in favor of using new commands or environments.

Is there a reason to choose one or another route to coloring large blocks of text?

In general, when is it better to use a new command vs. a new environment (if there is any substantial difference)?

UPDATE: Well I think I've come up with a partial answer: making commands following the model given in the linked answer (`\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}`) won't allow you to place multiple paragraphs within the scope of one command instance. Each paragraph requires a new instance of the coloring command (unless I'm doing something wrong). This would seem to be one reason to go the environment route.

FURTHER UPDATE: It turns out that the limitation of the command approach was a limitation of `\textcolor`, *not* some general limitation on new commands. Using `\color` allows you to color multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Some related (if not duplicate) questions: [What are the consideration when choosing either newcommand or newenvironment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102141) and [Class Design: Environment vs. Macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102241).

Comment: @AlanMunn That first question is a good duplicate, missed that one on my search. Since I've solved my particular issue, it is really the general question which is still of interest. The answers and comments of those questions are good enough for me. I issued a vote to close as duplicate.